# Buck installation with brew tries to hit an invalid url and throws 404

Tags: homebrew, bcel, buck

`brew install buck` throws

```
curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found
Trying a mirror...
==> Downloading https://www-us.apache.org/dist/commons/bcel/binaries/bcel-6.3.1-bin.tar.gz*
```

and  finally gives an error

```
Error: An exception occurred within a child process:
  DownloadError: Failed to download resource "ant--bcel"
Download failed: https://www-us.apache.org/dist/commons/bcel/binaries/bcel-6.3.1-bin.tar.gz*

The version bcel-6.3.1-bin.tar.gz does not exist in the binary- https://www-us.apache.org/dist/commons/bcel/binaries/
```

How do I get pass this?

Comment: Please edit your post and provide the tap where formula `buck` belong to. There's no a formula named `buck` in the builtin taps in Homebrew.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update:

The problem has already been reported at homebrew-core. And a [fix pr-44608](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/pull/44581) is waiting to be merged.

```sh
# use the pull request temporarily
brew install https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/raw/7f6d84a68ce8898d5f8bb1add2ed6d624cbb9598/Formula/ant.rb

# install buck from facebook/homebrew-fb
brew install buck
```

---

The [buck](https://github.com/facebook/homebrew-fb/blob/master/buck.rb) formula from tap [facebook/homebrew-fb](https://github.com/facebook/homebrew-fb) depends on formula `ant`. And download URL of the dependency `bcel` is broken in formula `ant`.

You didn't do anything wrong. It's a problem on the tap side. Open an issue under [homebrew/homebrew-core](https://github.com/homebrew/homebrew-core) and report this problem to them.

```rb
class Ant < Formula
  desc "Java build tool"
  homepage "https://ant.apache.org/"

  # ...

  resource "bcel" do
    # this url is broken, causing the build of `ant` failed
    url "https://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi?path=commons/bcel/binaries/bcel-6.3.1-bin.tar.gz"
    sha256 "ed1d281cb66dedb89611019168071fe22a50ff325253e2c453dc00423905cf9d"
  end

#...
```